# Use # symbol in document.querySelector() field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I'm developing a musical web app using Javascript and the library [Tonal.js](https://github.com/tonaljs/tonal)

Using Tonal.js i'll get (for example) the notes of a chord in american notation, which corresponds to letters from A to G.

As everyone knows flat notes are represented by **b** symbol, while sharp notes by **#** (for example *Ab* and *G#*)

I've already implemented a code that works fine in order to retrieve the notes from my html elements:

1) `Html`:

```
  <div id="pad">
    <ol class="even first">
      <li class='hex C' ><div class="note">C2</div></li>
      <li class='hex G' ><div class="note">G2</div></li>
      <li class='hex Db'><div class="note">Db3</div></li>
      <li class='hex A#'><div class="note">A#3</div></li>
      <li class='hex E' ><div class="note">E4</div></li>
    </ol>  
 </div>
```

2) `javascript`:

```
   full_chord = "CMaj7"
   chord_notes = Tonal.Chord.notes(full_chord);//takes a signature of a chord and returns the single notes that compose the chord
   var selected_notes = chord_notes.map(title => document.querySelectorAll("."+title)); //returns the html elements with the chord notes
```

This works fine, until i pass a note with a **#** in its signature. 
For example:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".C")); //works
document.querySelectorAll(".Cb")); //works
document.querySelectorAll(".C#")); //error: invalid selector
```

Is there a way to use the **#** symbol in my selector? Unfortunately i have to use it since it's a musical application.

Comment: Escape it as `\\#`. `#` is used for ID selection.

Comment: You can use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead of `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Olian04 This is what i needed, unfortunately you can't answer anymore because it's a duplicate, but i would have accepted this answer.

Comment: It's fine. Glad I could help